# Why isn't a celery backend pointing to an ip that's not local host not working?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, task, celery, amqp

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp://guest@192.168.99.100', broker='amqp://guest@192.168.99.100//')


@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I am successfully able to send celery tasks but when I try to get the results of the task it doesn't send them back. I think this is caused by the backend ip being set to an external ip and celery doesn't respect that.

```
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@192.168.99.100:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
```

Above is the output when I run 'Celery -A workers.tasks worker --loglevel=debug'

Comment: Have you tried with another account, other than guest?

Comment: @cantSleepNow yes I have but the threading switch seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this worked but it did

Run the command with the --pool=threads/solo switch

Celery -A proj.tasks worker -l info --pool=threads -n w1